# How to extract elements (title names, votes, views, answers for each title) from https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=month?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, dictionary

I could figure out the reading the page and storing the text to a file part (`urllib2`) but not the extraction of elements(`votes`, `title` ,...). 
The page is https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=month

How do I write a python script to get a webpage and then extract all the titles, no. of views, votes and answers received by each question?

Comment: Did you tried something?

Comment: Yes, I could extract the content using urllib2 but extracting of elements hasn't been what I hoped it'd be.

Comment: Please post the code you have & describe whats not working.

Comment: Don't scrape, its impolite and clunky, use the API: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions Note the `sort` param: *month – by the formula ordering the month tab*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to crawl the page, you can use libraries like [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) , but stackoverflow has very good and easy to use REST API , with sort features, which you can access and read about in here: 
https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/
for retrieving question for example, see this page: 
https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions